# Black hole solutions

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

I have a question, that may sound a little silly. Suppose that I have an $n$-dimensional metric given by

$$dS^2=e^{2 A(r)}[-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+\eta_{m n}\,dx^m\,dx^n]$$

with $A(r)$ is a warp factor and $f(r)$ is blackening factor. Besides the condition that $f(r_h)=0$ for the event horizon, what other conditions should obey the metric above to be considered as a black hole solution.

Comment: well the main one is that it should be a solution of the field equation

Comment: There should be some point r, where a curvature scalar constructed from your metric diverges, indicating a singularity.

Comment: What are the significance of a "warp factor" and why it is exponential?

Comment: @AndrewSteane: *it should be a solution of the field equation* **NO!!!** Metric being a black hole has *nothing* to do with any specific form of field equations. For example, a (reasonably small) deformation of Schwarzschild metric would be a black hole even  if one cannot point a specific gravity theory to which it belongs.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Yeah. That's right. That part was supposed ab initio. But my question goes in the line of what criterium should obey a metric to be considered a BH solution, supposing that it can be derived from the EEs.

Comment: @M.N.Raia It is just a smooth function used to add the property of conformality in the non-BH scenario. An exponential form is just to write a parametrization.

Comment: @A.V.S. So does sufficiently small deformation applied to a given (and proved) BH metric is still BH Solution? I considered that. But my question is a little more general.  I'm dealing with BH phenomenological metrics, some sort of ansatz, but it is no so clear to me what makes a proposed solution to be a BH one. I just started from the analytical properties associated to the blackening factor, but I think there should be more underneath.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, black hole is a region   of spacetime which cannot be seen from far away, more technically from the conformal spacetime boundary.

Let us start with the definition of *black hole region* from Wald's  textbook:
$$ B=M - J^{-}(\mathscr{I}^{+}),$$
where $M$ is our manifold (which is assumed to be asymptotically flat), $\mathscr{I}^{+}$ is the *future null infinity*, $J^{-}(\mathscr{I}^{+})$ is the *causal past* of future null infinity. So the black hole is the region of manifold that lie outside of causal past of future null infinity, in other words no signal (that propagates causally) can reach $\mathscr{I}^{+}$.

Can this definition be applied to OP's metric? Not directly, even with the OP's ansatz, because we do not know what is the conformal boundary for this metric and what are its causal properties. Instead one has to look at the explicit form of metric, identify asymptotic region(s) (let us denote it $\mathscr{I}$) and determine whether $r=r_h$ represents the boundary of the causal past ($J^{-}(\mathscr{I})$) of this region.

One thing to keep in mind, is that while metric does not have to satisfy any specific set of field equations to be a black hole, knowing the theory for which the metric is a solution of can give insight into the structure of asymptotic region.